# How do I open Unetbootin on my pc using Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: usb, 15.04, flash, unetbootin

I have installed Unetbootin on my pc.  I want to install Puppy Linux on my usb flash drive.

I cannot find Unetbootin on my pc.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and the Chromium browser.

Comment: How did you install Unetbootin? It should appear in your dash. Press button with Ubuntu logo and enter "Unet"

Comment: I installed Unetbootin using the Ubuntu Software Center.  I think I unlocked it form the dash by mistake.

Comment: After adding the comment above, I clicked on the button at the top of my side bar and typed Unetbootin on the search line.  A message appeared saying that noting matches my request.  My words.  I opened the Ubuntu Software Center, again.  I was told that Unetbootin is installed.

Answer (score 3):

After the installation via

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

the binary is in

```
/usr/bin/unetbootin
```

---

Open your Dash and type

```
unetbootin
```

or start `unetbootin` via terminal:

```
unetbootin
```

[image]